# Spring Boot: endpoints getting triggered by OPTIONS requests

Tags: reactjs, rest, spring-boot, http, axios

I'm developing an application with React in front-end end Spring Boot in back-end.
To make http requests I'm using Axios.
GET requests work fine, however, I'm having trouble with DELETE and POST methods. It seems that they are being triggered twice: one time by the preflight request and once more by the actual request.

My Javascript code:

```
deletePoll = () =>{
    axios.delete("anyurl/api/poll/delete",{
        params : {
            time_stamp : this.props.timestamp,
            channel_id : this.props.channelId
        }
    }).then(() => (console.log("success"))
    );
};
```

Here's where delete function is being triggered:

```
<div className="row align-content-center">
  <Button className="delete-poll-button" variant="primary" onClick={this.deletePoll}>
     Delete poll
  </Button>
</div>
```

The whole React component:

```
class DeletePollModal extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.deletePoll = this.deletePoll.bind(this);
}

deletePoll = () =>{
    axios.delete("anyurl/api/poll/delete",{
        params : {
            time_stamp : this.props.timestamp,
            channel_id : this.props.channelId
        }
    }).then(() => (console.log("success"))
    );
};

render(){
    return (
        <Modal className="delete-modal" show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide} size="lg" centered>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
                <Modal.Title>Do you really want to delete this poll?</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
                <h4 className="modal-heading">All poll data will be lost forever</h4>
                <div className="row align-content-center">
                    <Button className="delete-poll-button" variant="primary" onClick={this.deletePoll}>
                        Delete poll
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
                <Button variant="primary" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
                    Cancel
                </Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
        </Modal>
    );
}
```

}

And Spring Boot function:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public void deletePollById(@RequestParam String time_stamp, @RequestParam String channel_id)
{
    System.out.println("It's happening");
    pollService.deletePollById(time_stamp, channel_id);
}
```

[image]
[image]

As you can see from the images, only one delete request is sent and the function is called 2 times

Also, if I send a POST request using Postman, everything works fine, sending an OPTIONS request does not trigger the function. However, with Axios, deleteByPollId gets called 2 times.
Why is this happening and how can I fix this problem so that the function only gets called one time?

Edit:

Looks like the problem is with the back-end.
The endpoint is being triggered, indeed, by the OPTIONS request. I've managed to achieve the same behaviour with Postman by adding 
'Access-Control-Request-Method' : 'DELETE' header.
What is extremely weird, I found a temporary fix:

```
@DeleteMapping(value = "/delete", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE})
public ResponseEntity mockDelete(@RequestHeader("Access-Control-Request-Method") String accessControl){
    System.out.println("Second delete method");
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Adding this method below the deletePollById method fixed the problem. However, it doesn't even get triggered. 
Can anyone explain why the back-end application is behaving this way?

Comment: the posted code seems fine, and as you try the post request from postman that means the Spring Boot application working correct, is there is a chance you call the deletePoll function twice in the script.

Comment: I'm actually checking requests that are being sent and received by the app. One options request and one delete request, that's it

Comment: Are you using absolute urls or relative urls ? OPTION preflight happens only with absolute urls, also it should be first.

Comment: Correct, options request comes first. I'm using full url's, for instance, "http://localhost:8080/api/poll/delete"

Answer (score 0):

You might have some problems in your component Life cycle hooks, post complete component to know about the exact problem.

Comment: If first request is an OPTIONS request, then it’s a preflight request. Don’t worry about it, follow this link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request

Comment: I understand that, I've read about. I only see the fact, that one delete request is sent one single time and an API endpoint is triggered two times

Comment: Does your deletePoll call actually runs two times on server?

Comment: Yes, you can see from the screenshot I've added in the question that print statement is called two times

Comment: You can then just avoid preflight requests by configuring cors properly and make your request as “Simple request”. You can look into Cors npm package. If it doesn’t solve the problem then check that your event might get caught on bubbling up else where.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a DELETE or POST you don't have to worry about the OPTIONS request. It is normal and the endpoint will be called just once.

n fact, OPTIONS are most of the time informative requests launched by the browser.
It is linked with the Access-Control-Allow methods and it can be used to have a self-documented rest api.

Wikipedia says :

Returns the HTTP methods that the server supports for the specified URL. 
This can be used to check the functionality of a web server by requesting '*' instead of a specific resource.

You can find some info here : [w3](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)
And here too : [link](http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html)

So, your server needs to indicate to the browser that the request it tries to do is allowed by setting the Access-Control-Allow methods

Comment: I understand that. That's why I can't understand why the options request triggers an API endpoint. You can see that in the screenshots